# Обновление данных через this angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Есть директива в которую передаются данные :

```
export default class MenuDir {

  constructor() {
    this.scope = { menu: '=', selected: '=' },
    this.restrict = 'E';
    this.controllerAs = 'menuCtrl';
    this.controller = MenuDirCtrl;
    this.templateUrl = '/templates/menu-template.html'
  }
}

class MenuDirCtrl {

  constructor($scope) {
    this.$scope = $scope;
    this.data = $scope.menu;

    **setTimeout(() => {console.log($scope.menu); console.log(this); return 1}, 3000);**
  }

  selectMenu(menu) {
    this.$scope.selected = menu;
  }

  isSelected(menu) {
    return menu === this.$scope.selected;
  }
}
```

HTML :

```
<app-dir>
  <menu-dir menu="appCtrl.data" selected="appCtrl.selected"></menu-dir>
</app-dir>
```

menu="appCtrl.data" - получает данные с сервера и естественно data появляется позже инициализации, но когда приходить передается но повторно не переопределяется в this.data = $scope.menu; и this.data остается пустым, как решить эту проблему не запуская руками digest цикл ?

Comment: без функции получения ничего непонятно, но скорее всего там используется какой-нибудь левый jQuery - и не запуская _digest цикл_ решить нельзя, так как по другому ангуляр никак не узнает, что что-то надо обновить. Возможно стоит отказаться от ангуляра, если не используются его возможности

Comment: а смысл тут вообще скоп использовать? да еще и сохранять его в контроллер

Comment: @Grundy там передается параметр в директиву через атрибут, menu: '=', но я использую синтаксис this, а не через scope, и получается что this не обновляется

Comment: это все потому, что ты неправильно его используешь

Comment: scope кеширую чтобы потом помять его значение в родительской директиве

Comment: какой-то изврат

Comment: [bindtocontroller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-bindtocontroller-) и скоп не нужен, пока тебе не понадобились события

Comment: а как тогда получать данные из атрибутов  this.scope = { menu: '=', selected: '=' }, ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43366/discussion-between-grundy-and-khotey-vitaliy).

Answer (score 1):

В конструкторе директивы добавить

```
this.bindToController = true;
```

И теперь в контролере директивы `menuCtrl` есть свойства

```
this.scope = { menu: '=', selected: '=' },
```

Подробнее http://blog.thoughtram.io/angularjs/2015/01/02/exploring-angular-1.3-bindToController.html

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.